# release dynamically added subviews of tableview in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am working on one application in which i have created one table view using custom cell.In custom cell i have added imageview.i am parsing images from server and add that images to tableview now when user press on delete button i want to reload tableview data but the problem is that previously added subviews are not released.I also use code for release it but it not works.
Here is sample code and image of tableview

```
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{       
    [images removeObjectAtIndex:selectedImage];

    for(id object in [self.view subviews])
    {
        [object removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //for (UIImageView *aLabel in [tv subviews]) [aLabel removeFromSuperview];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove object from table view or uiview.

Comment: if u give me more code then i can answer u

Comment: @iPhoneiPadDev i want to remove imageviews which are dynamically added into tableview.Inshort remove object from table view

Comment: @AppleVijay UIImageView *ImagesVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgs];
            ImagesVw.frame=CGRectMake(xcord_img+space_img*j, ycord_img, width_img, height_img);
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:ImagesVw.frame];
            button.tag = [tagValue intValue];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            [button release];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:ImagesVw];
            [ImagesVw release];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" table method, put below code before you add the image subview.

```
UIImageView *img = nil;
NSArray *Array = [cell subviews];
for (img in Array){
    if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [img removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Also "cell" should be initialize once.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

---

```
CGFloat xcord_img,ycord_img,height_img,width_img;    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

UIImageView *img = nil;
NSArray *Array = [cell subviews];
for (img in Array)
{
    if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [img removeFromSuperview];          
     }
}
UIButton *btn = nil;
NSArray *Array1 = [cell subviews];
for (btn in Array1){
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
space_img = 100;
xcord_img = 20;
ycord_img = 20;
height_img = 70;
width_img = 70;
int i=0; 


for(int j=0; j<rownum && indexPath.row*rownum+j<18; 
{
    NSString *tagValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row*rownum+j];

magazineData *obj=[[magazineData alloc]init];
obj=[mData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *imgs=[UIImage imageWithData:obj.mImage]; 
UIImageView *ImagesVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgs];
ImagesVw.frame=CGRectMake(xcord_img+space_img*j, ycord_img, width_img, height_img);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:ImagesVw.frame];
button.tag = [tagValue intValue];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
//[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
//[button release];
[cell addSubview:button];
//[cell.contentView addSubview:ImagesVw];      
[cell addSubview: ImagesVw];
[cell bringSubviewToFront: ImagesVw];

//[ImagesVw release];
i++;
}
```

### return cell;

Hi have updated code. Please review it.

Cheers

Comment: hi, I tryed your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath table method but it released all views and gives black screen only

Comment: Hi, here "cell" is tableView cell. And make sure that, you are calling the above function after "cell" is initialized. And also make sure that, after calling this function, you will add the images into cell. (Not before the calling this function).

Comment: And cell will be initiaize once only. right? I have update the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to provide your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method?

Comment: Yes but here my chat limit is over so i post screen shot of this method below side

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3608/discussion-between-manish007-and-ios-developer)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that, and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you release the subviews after adding them to the view since the view will retain them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

//Format function

```
    CGFloat xcord_img,ycord_img,height_img,width_img;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    space_img = 100;
    xcord_img = 20;
    ycord_img = 20;
    height_img = 70;
    width_img = 70;
    int i=0; 
    for(int j=0; j<rownum && indexPath.row*rownum+j<18; j++)
    {
        NSString *tagValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row*rownum+j];

        magazineData *obj=[[magazineData alloc]init];
        obj=[mData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UIImage *imgs=[UIImage imageWithData:obj.mImage]; 
        UIImageView *ImagesVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgs];
        ImagesVw.frame=CGRectMake(xcord_img+space_img*j, ycord_img, width_img, height_img);
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:ImagesVw.frame];
        button.tag = [tagValue intValue];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        [button release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ImagesVw];

        [ImagesVw release];
        i++;
    }
    return cell;
```

Comment: Hi, your code works fine but it will remove both images on reload tableview i want to delete only one image.I also check it by putting break point, the control also calls tableview methodes on reload and release subview but further it will not add remaining one imageview.You can see the screen in above image

Comment: Hi, there may be some issue in your for loop. There may be some condition change so that, it can add one image. This code is working fine for me.

Comment: Hi,Thank you very much for your efforts for me,now your code works fine without any problem and finally i got solution

Comment: Great. Finally you got the solution.